# 401 Authentication when making request involving another url

Tags: reactjs, django, authentication

I am trying to make a GET request to my django backend but when I do i get a 401 and this is after i have logged in already.

```
async get_SearchResults(id) {
    console.log(this.state.logged_in)
    try{
        let response = await axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/Anime_Creator_App/videos/${id}/`)
        console.log(response.data)
        this.setState({
            search_results: response.data,
        });
    } catch (er){
        console.log('ERROR in get_SearchResults', er)
    }

}
```

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'http://localhost:3000',
    'http://127.0.0.1:8000',
)

JWT_AUTH = {
    'JWT_RESPONSE_PAYLOAD_HANDLER': 'Anime_Creator_App.utils.my_jwt_response_handler'
}
```

```
def my_jwt_response_handler(token, user=None, request=None):
    return {
        'token': token,
        'user': UserSerializer(user, context={'request': request}).data
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It needed headers Authentication in axios call